# For how many days will the food last in garrison?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> A garrison has sufficient food for $75$ soldiers for a period of $90$ days.
>   After $10$ days, one third of the soldiers leave. After another $10$ 
>   days, $5$ soldiers return, From this day on, how many days will the
>   food last ?

I did

$F \propto s\times d \\
F_{1} =k\times75\times 90 \\
F_{2} =k\times50\times 80 \\
F_{3} =k\times55\times 70 $

Now I don't know how to proceed .

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: If each soldier eats one meat pie every day, how many meat pies does the garrison start with? And how many meat pies are consumed in the first 10 days? The second 10 days? So how many are left for the 55 soldiers after that?

Comment: I wish all the responders would give the OP a chance to figure it out for themselves in cases like this. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned it the comments, imagine every soldier needs a meal a day. You start with $90\cdot75$ meals.

After 10 days, you have $75\cdot10$ meals less.

25 soldies leave, so in the following 10 days, only $50\cdot10$ meals are eaten.

Than 5 soldiers return, so you have 55 soldiers. All you have to do is evaluate in how many days will the soldiers eat the remaining meals.

Answer (score 1):

$F_{0} = 75*90$ (food for 90 days and 75)

$F_{1} = F_{0}-75*10$ (75 soldiers eat for 10 days)

$F_{2} = F_{1}-50*10$ (50 soldiers eat for 10 days)

$F_{3} = F_{2}-t*55$ (55 soldiers eat for $t$ days)

I guess you can figure out what $F_{3}$ is.

Then calculate $t$, the remaining days.

Comment: I didn't get what is $F_{3}$

Comment: @RK "From this day on, how many days will the food last ?" You should calculate after how many days the supply ($F$) is used up. $F_{3}$ is the final amount of food, so $F_{3}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say each soldier eats $1$ meal per day .
You have $75*90$ meals.First $10$ days you use $75*10$ meals. Second $10$ days, you use $50*10$ meals. You now have $M= 75*90 - 75*10 - 50*10$ meals = $5500$ meals.  You now have $55$ soldiers. Therefore, no. of days = $M/55 =100$.